# What is phantom JS error code 1?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I get error code #1 when rendering some web pages but not others in phantomJS. The block is in a 3rd party module that calls phantomJS to take the screenshot.

```
  if (path) {
    phantomProc.on('exit', function(code) {
      if (!calledCallback) {
        calledCallback = true;

        // No need to run the timeout anymore.
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        cb(code
          ? new Error('PhantomJS exited with return value ' + code)
          : null);
      }
    });
```

What is error code 1? I can't find any reference to phantomJS error codes online.

Comment: `  var phantomProc = childProcess.spawn(options.phantomPath, phantomArgs);` It's just a call to the phantomjs child process.

Comment: It could be Invalid Function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`code` is the return code the script execution.

This is generally manage inside the client script, by calling `phantom.exit(code)`.
The convention on phantomjs examples, is to use `1` for invalid parameters.

For example, check the [loadspeed.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/loadspeed.js)

```
if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
...
}
```